# Problems with Kubuntu on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04, raspberrypi

I've tried to install the kubuntu desktop environment on my Raspberry, but it crashes with a cloud-init line.
The normal installation of Ubuntu 20.04 works fine, but after the reboot of the system it hangs on this point.
Is there a bug?
Thanks
Sebastian